# How to change CSS property by JS and use transition?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I am setting up a CSS effect in JavaScript (`filter` property) and in the next line I am setting up that property to `none`. My image has `filter` equal to `none`, but I want to make it with `transition`.

Without the last line (when I’m setting the property back to `none`) if I disable the `filter` property in the console it works with `transition`.

```
loadImg.style.filter = `blur(${value})`;
loadImg.style.transition = `-webkit-filter ${transitionDuration} ${timing} ${delay}`;
loadImg.style.filter = 'none';
```

I know it’s because of JavaScript, but I have no idea how to make it work with `transition`.

Comment: Does the element have a filter-property when first loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you are setting the transition of the --webkit-filter property, but you set the filter property.
Secondly as jneander mentioned the change is happening too quickly you should wrap it in a requestAnimationFrame or a timeout

Here is a working demo with the fixes:

```js
let value = "15px";
let loadImg = document.getElementById("block");

let transitionDuration = "1s";
let timing = "ease-in-out";
let delay = "1s";

loadImg.style.filter = `blur(${value})`;
requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
  loadImg.style.transition = `filter ${transitionDuration} ${timing} ${delay}`;
  
  loadImg.style.filter = 'none';
});
```

```css
#block {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The application of `filter = 'none'` is likely happening too quickly to allow for the initial filter value to be applied and rendered. If you wrap the second transition in a double- `requestAnimationFrame`, that will allow the renderer to establish the initial blur state to transition away from.

```
const loadImg = document.querySelector('.loadImg')

const value = '20px'
const transitionDuration = '1s'
const timing = 'linear'
const delay = '0s'

loadImg.style.filter = `blur(${value})`;

requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    loadImg.style.transition = `-webkit-filter ${transitionDuration} ${timing} ${delay}`;
    loadImg.style.filter = 'none';  
  })
})
```

For more information on the double-requestAnimationFrame: [How does double requestAnimationFrame work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145740/how-does-double-requestanimationframe-work)