# visibility issue with nested collapsible

Tags: javascript, html

`whenever i expand the nested collapsible, the visibility of its parent is not calculated properly. A few of the nested get missed out on the screen

Here is the html code & the js code to handle the scroll height

```js
// Get all collapsible buttons
const collapsibles = document.getElementsByClassName('collapsible');

// Add click event listener for each collapsible
for (let i = 0; i < collapsibles.length; i++) {
  collapsibles[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');
    const content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }

    // Get all nested collapsible buttons within this collapsible
    const nestedCollapsibles = content.getElementsByClassName('nested-collapsible');

    // Loop through nested collapsibles and expand or collapse them accordingly
    for (let j = 0; j < nestedCollapsibles.length; j++) {
      const nestedContent = nestedCollapsibles[j].nextElementSibling;
      if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
        if (!nestedContent.style.maxHeight) {
          nestedContent.style.maxHeight = nestedContent.scrollHeight + 'px';
          content.style.maxHeight = (parseInt(content.style.maxHeight) + nestedContent.scrollHeight) + 'px'; // Add nested collapsible's scroll height to parent collapsible's scroll height
        } else {
          nestedContent.style.maxHeight = null;
          content.style.maxHeight = (parseInt(content.style.maxHeight) - nestedContent.scrollHeight) + 'px'; // Subtract nested collapsible's scroll height from parent collapsible's scroll height
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color:blue;
}
```

````html
<div id="HotLikeMiami">
  <div class="HLM">
    <div class="HLMRow">

      <div class="HLMTitle">
        <h1 class="sub-title">Fantastic League</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="HLMImg">
        <img src="fantasticLeague.png">
      </div>
      <div class="HLMDetails">
        <p>A 2D Top Down Shooter game which heavily focuses on Enemy AI. I have made an attempt to build this project from ground up. I have used SFML for rendering shapes and textures, the rest is made from scratch. The project involves the integration
          of complex enemy AI. A simple Data-Oriented Design approach has been followed in this project for handling different events and messages by the enemies. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="MyContibution">
        <button class="collapsible">My Contribution</button>
        <div class="ContributionContent">
          <p>Got a lot of contribution</p>
          <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible">My Contribution</button>
          <div class="ContributionContent">
            <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
              the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
          </div>

          <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible">My Contribution</button>
          <div class="ContributionContent">
            <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
              the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
          </div>

          <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible">My Contribution</button>
          <div class="ContributionContent">
            <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
              the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>```

</kbd>
````

I need help with the calculation and what is messing with the visibility

i expect all the nested to be independent and whenever expanded they increase the height of the parent visibility
Here the last nested gets cut out:

[image]

---

Comment: Currently your parent has a fixed `max-height` whenever it opens. The trick is to set the `max-height` to `auto` after opening is complete. This can be accomplished by listening for a [`transitionend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) event to capture the end of the opening transition.

Comment: Are you just trying to collapse and expand the text-blocks? Could you make it work in the code snippet as much as you can, it will help us understand what you mean with calculation and visibility.

Comment: @SaroGFX it's happening quite similar to this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

Comment: @EmielZuurbier something like this for the above js code?
const transition = content.querySelector(".transition");

    transition.ontransitionend = () => {
    content.maxHeight = auto;

also, here's example link. You can explain over here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your code to work properly with dynamic heights and responsiveness.

Fist check if you're expanding or collapsing. We can figure this out by getting the result of `classList.toggle`, which is `true` if the class is added, `false` if removed.

I've added a wrapper inside of each `ContributionContent`. This wrapper will be responsible for calculating the *total height* of the content inside. This is needed because the height of `ContributionContent` will fluctuate.

Listen for the `transitionend` event to set the max height to `none`. Only set the height whenever the accordion is expanding. When closing `0px` should be honored.

Since the max height is set to `none`when expanded, we have to use a Double Request Animation Frame (Double RAF) to be able to first set the height and then transition to `0px` when closing. This a (hacky) technique to perform tasks *after* a render has happened. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145740/how-does-double-requestanimationframe-work) about Double RAFs.

```js
// Get all collapsible buttons
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');

// Add click event listener for each collapsible.
for (const collapsible of collapsibles) {
  collapsible.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const button = event.target;
    const isExpanding = button.classList.toggle('active');
    const content = button.nextElementSibling;
    const wrapper = content.firstElementChild;
    
    // Get the calculated height of the wrapper.
    const { height } = wrapper.getBoundingClientRect();
    content.style.maxHeight = height + 'px';
    
    // Remove max height after an exapnding transition.
    content.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
      if (isExpanding) {
        content.style.maxHeight = 'none';
      }
    }, { once: true });
    
    // Hack to force a closing transition.
    if (!isExpanding) {
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          content.style.maxHeight = '0px';
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}

.collapsible + * {
  display: grid; /* This forces the wrapper to account for the margins. It avoids a jump. */
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 500ms ease-out;
}
```

```html
<div id="HotLikeMiami">
  <div class="HLM">
    <div class="HLMRow">

      <div class="HLMTitle">
        <h1 class="sub-title">Fantastic League</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="HLMImg">
        <img src="fantasticLeague.png">
      </div>
      <div class="HLMDetails">
        <p>A 2D Top Down Shooter game which heavily focuses on Enemy AI. I have made an attempt to build this project from ground up. I have used SFML for rendering shapes and textures, the rest is made from scratch. The project involves the integration
          of complex enemy AI. A simple Data-Oriented Design approach has been followed in this project for handling different events and messages by the enemies. </p>
      </div>

      <div class="MyContibution">
        <button class="collapsible active">My Contribution</button>
        <div class="ContributionContent">
          <div class="ContributionContentWrapper">
            <p>Got a lot of contribution</p>
            
            <div>
              <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible active">My Contribution</button>
              <div class="ContributionContent">
                <div class="ContributionContentWrapper">
                  <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
                    the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible active">My Contribution</button>
              <div class="ContributionContent">
                <div class="ContributionContentWrapper">
                  <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
                    the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div>
              <button class="collapsible nested-collapsible active">My Contribution</button>
              <div class="ContributionContent">
                <div class="ContributionContentWrapper">
                  <p>1. This process involves the development and integration of states like Game Menu, Splash Screen, InGame, Game Over etc states. These states are fetched with delta time which is calculated from the Game Loop. ​ 2. This stage also includes
                    the development of Asset Manager, Input Manager etc</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

As a closing note. W3Schools has a lot of good examples, but they are notoriously outdated. When looking for examples, find out how old they are and if they use up-to-date practices.