# Slide image vanish before making the transition

Tags: javascript, css, slider, css-transitions

I have an image `slider` with 4 images. To **navigate** between them there are 2 ways: 2 buttons in the corners of the slider and a small slider indicator to choose an image represented as dots in the bottom of the slider.

Each slider has a `transition` property of **0.6s** as follows :

```
.carousel-inner > .item {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 470px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}
```

What I would like to do is navigate between these images smoothly with a `transition` effect, so if I choose an image that is located after the selected one both will move to the left and if the image is in the is before the selected one both the imager move to the right.

The effect that I am looking for is precisely like [this one](https://developer.accuweather.com/).

```js
let slideIndex = 1;

console.log("fdsf");

function showSlide(n) {
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-inner > .item");
    let dots = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-indicators li");
    dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("active");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    } else if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    } else {
        slideIndex = n;
    }

    const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-inner > .item.active");

    activeSlide.classList.add("left");
    activeSlide.classList.remove("active");

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.left = "100%";

    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("left");

    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("next");
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("left");

    activeSlide.classList.remove("active");
    activeSlide.classList.remove("left");

    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("next");
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("left");

    dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
}


$(".carousel-indicators li").on("click", function () {
    showSlide(parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-slide-to")) + 1)
})
```

```css
.carousel {
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: 20px;
    }
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 15;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -30%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000 \9;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner > .item.slide1 {
    background-position: center 10%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 470px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner > .next.left, .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    left: 0
}

.carousel-inner > .active.left {
    left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner > .active, .carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control.right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
    left: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left::before {
    content: url(../images/icons/left-arrow.png);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}


.carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    right: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon:empty {
    width: 1em;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-right::before {
    content: url(../images/icons/right-arrow.png);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div
          class="item slide1 active"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline1"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide2"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline2"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide3"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline3"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide4"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elements that have `display: none` can't transition as they don't have a beginning and an end to transition from and to. Only show and don't show. So you'd have to overcome that issue by showing the new slide in the position that you it to, then wait for the new slide to render, and only then slide it in while moving the old slide out.

Comment: Thank you @EmielZuurbier, I have solved the problem, please check my answer and tell me please if you have any changes you think I can add to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `setTimeout`, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). More specifically a [double `requestAnimationFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44145740/how-does-double-requestanimationframe-work) which enables us to wait for the browser to paint the next frame and do something after that happens. This way you don't have to guess the time to wait until `display: block` has been painted by the browser.

Same goes for the second timeout, but there you want to do something *after* the transition has finished. You can accomplish this more accurately by listening to the [transitionend event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event). And to make sure that the event is only listened to once per slide change, add `{ once: true }` as options param to `addEventListener`.

I took the liberty to add a flag `isAnimating` to the slider to indicate that the slider is moving and nothing should happen until the animation is finished.

```js
let slideIndex = 1;
let isAnimating = false;

function afterNextRepaint(callback) {
  if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
    return;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      callback();
    });
  });
}

function showSlide(n) {
  if (isAnimating || slideIndex === n) {
    return;
  }

  let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-inner > .item");
  let dots = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-indicators li");
  dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("active");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1;
  } else if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length;
  } else {
    slideIndex = n;
  }

  isAnimating = true;

  const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-inner > .item.active");
  const nextSlide = slides[slideIndex - 1];
  const nextDot = dots[slideIndex - 1];

  nextSlide.classList.add("next");

  afterNextRepaint(() => {
    activeSlide.classList.add("left");
    nextSlide.classList.add("left");
  });

  nextSlide.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
    nextSlide.classList.add("active");

    activeSlide.classList.remove("left");
    activeSlide.classList.remove("active");

    nextSlide.classList.remove("next");
    nextSlide.classList.remove("left");

    nextDot.classList.add("active");

    isAnimating = false;
  }, { once: true });
}


$(".carousel-indicators li").on("click", function() {
  showSlide(parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-slide-to")) + 1)
})
```

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel-indicators {
    bottom: 20px;
  }
}

.carousel-indicators {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 15;
  width: 60%;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: -30%;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
}

ul,
ol {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 1px;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #000 \9;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner>.item.slide1 {
  background-position: center 10%;
}

.carousel-inner>.item {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 470px;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
  transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel-inner>.prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.carousel-inner>.next {
  left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner>.prev {
  left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner>.next.left,
.carousel-inner>.prev.right {
  left: 0
}

.carousel-inner>.active.left {
  left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner>.active.right {
  left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner>.active {
  left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner>.active,
.carousel-inner>.next,
.carousel-inner>.prev {
  display: block;
}

.carousel-control.left {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control.right {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
  left: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left::before {
  content: url(../images/icons/left-arrow.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  right: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev,
.carousel-control .icon-next,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left,
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 5;
  display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon:empty {
  width: 1em;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-right::before {
  content: url(../images/icons/right-arrow.png);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item slide1 active" style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          ">
        <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline1"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="item slide2" style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          ">
        <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline2"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="item slide3" style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          ">
        <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline3"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="item slide4" style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          ">
        <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your assistance. I have identified the error that arose from attempting to determine the timing, which became evident once the transition time was adjusted to 2 seconds. Specifically, the active class was removed before the transition was finished, causing the image to disappear prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by updating the function `showSlide`, by changing the order and the way the `classes`' names are being removed and added to **elements** of the `transition` when changing the **slide**, I also used `settimeout` function since the operation must be divided into steps :

1. Add the class `next` to the element we want to show, update its `display`, and `render` it into the dom.
2. The 1st `timeout` is responsible for adding the class `left` for both elements. That class is responsible for shifting both the images (old and new) to the `left` by **100%** (the shift will no happen immediately since the element with the class `next` and `left` has a **left** of 0)
3. The 2nd `timeout` will be responsible for the final updates and it will update both the elements by adding and removing their final classes.

Here is how it looks now :

```js
let slideIndex = 1;

function showSlide(n) {
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-inner > .item");
    let dots = document.querySelectorAll(".carousel-indicators li");
    dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("active");

    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    } else if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    } else {
        slideIndex = n;
    }

    const activeSlide = document.querySelector(".carousel-inner > .item.active");
    slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("next");

    setTimeout(() => {
        activeSlide.classList.add("left");
        slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("left");

        setTimeout(() => {
            slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");

            activeSlide.classList.remove("left");
            activeSlide.classList.remove("active");

            slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("next");
            slides[slideIndex - 1].classList.remove("left");

            dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add("active");
        }, 800)
    }, 200)
}


$(".carousel-indicators li").on("click", function () {
    showSlide(parseInt(this.getAttribute("data-slide-to")) + 1)
})
```

```css
.carousel {
    position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: 20px;
    }
}

.carousel-indicators {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 15;
    width: 60%;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: -30%;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
}

ul, ol {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000 \9;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.carousel-inner > .item.slide1 {
    background-position: center 10%;
}

.carousel-inner > .item {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 470px;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out left;
}

.carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .next {
    left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .prev {
    left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner > .next.left, .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
    left: 0
}

.carousel-inner > .active.left {
    left: -100%
}

.carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 100%
}

.carousel-inner > .active {
    left: 0;
}

.carousel-inner > .active, .carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
    display: block;
}

.carousel-control.left {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#00000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control.right {
    right: 0;
    left: auto;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 top, 100% top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0), color-stop(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0001) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00000000', endColorstr='#80000000', GradientType=1);
}

.carousel-control {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 15%;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left {
    left: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-left::before {
    content: url(../images/icons/left-arrow.png);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}


.carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    right: 50%;
}

.carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
    display: inline-block;
}

.glyphicon:empty {
    width: 1em;
}

.glyphicon-chevron-right::before {
    content: url(../images/icons/right-arrow.png);
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class=""></li>
      </ol>

      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div
          class="item slide1 active"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline1"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide2"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline2"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide3"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Cat_August_2010-4.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline3"></div>
        </div>

        <div
          class="item slide4"
          style="
            background-image: url(https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-67586673,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-3918697,resizemode-6,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg);
            background-size: cover;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
          "
        >
          <div id="page-header-tagline" class="tagline4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>

      <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice. I do have some comments to add. I'll post an answer with a modified snippet.