# vuejs: Changing HTML before confirm-prompt

Tags: vue.js

My goal with vue.js is to change the HTML before a confirm-prompt appears.

**index.html**

```html
<div id='vueexample'>
    <button @click="colorFunction()">Click me!</button>
    <p v-if="userIsDeciding" style="background-color: yellow;">The user has to decide.</p>
</div>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js'></script>
<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#vueexample',
        data: { userIsDeciding: false },
        methods: {
            colorFunction: function() {             
                this.userIsDeciding = true; 
            if(confirm("please confirm")){
                //some stuff
            }   
                this.userIsDeciding = false;    
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

[(Here is the fiddle.)](https://jsfiddle.net/9pa7b4gz/)

**The problem**: p-tag isn't shown before the confirm-prompt.

**My question**: How can I make p-tag shown before the confirm-prompt?

Any help is appreciated ❤️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) function:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#vueexample',
    data() { 
    return { userIsDeciding: false }
  },
    methods: {
        colorFunction: function() {             
            this.userIsDeciding = true; 
      setTimeout(() => {
        if(confirm("please confirm")){
        //some stuff
        }   
        this.userIsDeciding = false;
      }, 0)
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js'></script>
<div id='vueexample'>
        <button @click="colorFunction()">Click me!</button>
    <p v-if="userIsDeciding" style="background-color: yellow;">The user has to decide.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It looks a bit hacky, but I think it's the quickest solution, so I'll take it!

Answer (score 2):

##### Solution

Many people have dealt with this before, perhaps one of the most relevant answers to this – which is better than `setTimeout(..., 0)` – is a package.

- [VueJS Github Issue: How to wait for a browser re-render?](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200#issuecomment-526996911) - Github Issue Answer
- [vue-force-next-tick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-force-next-tick) - NPM Package

Positive feedback has been received regarding the use of the package mentioned here, so I thought I would check out how it works. It's quite simple.

- [`doubleRequestAnimationFrame()` method](https://github.com/twickstrom/vue-force-next-tick/blob/e7aaf743bc571a871b9d25353be519b1b72a825d/src/index.js#L1) - `vue-force-next-tick\src\index.js`

Actually, the basic concept is embedding the native JavaScript function requestAnimationFrame() within itself, which seems to always wait for the rendering to refresh in every case.

The creator of the function named this function `forceNextTick()`, which can be invoked without a callback function.

If there is no callback, it invokes the `doubleRequestAnimationFrame()` as an `new Promise`.

Try out the package, **or take a look at the package-less implementation of the solution it applies**:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vueexample',
  data() { 
    return { userIsDeciding: false }
  },
  methods: {
    colorFunction: function () {             
      this.userIsDeciding = true; 
      
      // SOURCE
      // https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9200#issuecomment-526996911
      // https://github.com/twickstrom/vue-force-next-tick
      // https://github.com/twickstrom/vue-force-next-tick/blob/e7aaf743bc571a871b9d25353be519b1b72a825d/src/index.js#L1
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
          if(confirm("please confirm")){
            //some stuff
          }   
          this.userIsDeciding = false;
        })
      })
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js'></script>
<div id='vueexample'>
  <button @click="colorFunction()">Click me!</button>
  <p v-if="userIsDeciding" style="background-color: yellow;">The user has to decide.</p>
</div>
```

##### More information

- [`window.requestAnimationFrame()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) - MDN Docs
- [How does double requestANimationFrame work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44146560/15167500) - StackOverflow answer
- [Experience with doubling the requestAnimationFrame](https://dev.to/nikitadmitr/the-other-side-of-using-requestanimationframe-4jk6) - dev.to post

Comment: Thanks for your effort! For the moment I'll pick the quick and dirty setTimeout thing though.